# How does Instagram find my Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, instagram

So I deleted Facebook app and messenger and also removed Facebook from the list of accounts in settings. I also cleared Instagram data and deleted the app itself.

What is puzzling me is that when I reinstall Instagram it prompts me to login with my old Facebook account.

How does it know about this account? Where are the remnants of it being stored?

Backup appears to be off too

Answer (score 0):

Apps that use the newer Android standard of data backup will store their basic information on Google's servers...

Look in `Settings - Backup & Reset` and there is an option called Automatic Restore (or something similar), it's description literally says "When reinstalling an app, restore backed up settings and data".

If you do not want the applications data restored, remove the app, turn this option off and reinstall the applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but upon checking it was already all set to "off"

Comment: Hmm... Odd... Browser cache or cookies perhaps? (Yeah, I'm reaching a little)

Comment: All cleared too. It's clearly grabbing my Facebook info from somewhere though and even the "find people to follow" links up with the old Facebook friends list.

Comment: @acejavelin The IMEI collected by the Facebook app before its uninstallation and the one collected by Instagram match, perhaps? Almost all of the Facebook owned apps require unique ID data.